# Google Play very strange auto-suggest on search box

Tags: autocomplete

I try to find a good name for a game I want to publish and I start searching for the competition. When I start typing Google Play shows me up to 5 suggestions.
The very weird thing is that I get some suggestions that nobody will type more than once in a lifetime.
I thought that those suggestions are based on what people search the most, but i think this is not the case.

Some examples:
Start typing "yy" and you will get "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyrryyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"

Start typing "jx" and you will get "jxjdjejrdjdjjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjjeixjfaajfaqjafqjfjfqjafjfqjrqqjfjfqjfqjqfjfqjfajfqjfqjfqjfqjqfjfqjfqjrjfjfjdjjhdjzhzhzhxhzhzhzzjzjxjzhjdhzjdðŸ˜±ðŸ˜±bðŸ˜œðŸ˜šðŸ˜œðŸ˜œðŸ’•ðŸ’˜ðŸ’ŽðŸ’˜ðŸ’ŽðŸ’¬ðŸ’•â›ªâ›ºðŸ©ud"

Can anyone explain how those suggestions got there???

Comment: They aren't unique to you, so this isn't something that can be answered here.  The most likely reason is someone else actually searched for that and it got stored.

Comment: Strange, but true... [Autocomplete on official Google Support](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/106230) mentions "*The algorithm is based on a number of objective factors, including how often others have searched for a word. The algorithm is designed to reflect the range of info on the web. So just like the web, **the search terms you see might seem strange or surprising.***". Also, this question will probably boost the popularity of these 2 keywords :)

Comment: @Paul I also searched for my game several time and that term didn't get stored

Comment: @AndrewT. Your link is interesting. About boosting these words in the future because of the question, probability true. People reading this question will actually try for themselves to see if they appear, which will actually boost them in the future, so I guess Google gets its database from the future :P